# normal bundle over a smooth submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

i am struggling to show that for a $n-dim.$  smooth submaifold $M  \subset \Bbb R^k$ the normal bundle $NM=\dot \cup_{p\in M}(T_pM)^\bot \subset ι^*T \Bbb R^k\cong M\times \Bbb R^k $ is a smooth rank $(k-n)-dim.$  vektor bundle over $M$.

Where $ι: M \to \Bbb R^k $ denote the inclusion map.

help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which part do you need help with? The rank? Do you know what the rank of the tangent bundle is?

Comment: should´t it be n .

Comment: Yes. The tangent bundle of an $n$-dimensional manifold is rank $n$. Therefore its orthogonal complement is rank $k-n$.

Comment: i thought it should be k-n because m is a submanifold in $\Bbb R^k$

Comment: I didn't see any manifold of dimension $m$ in your question?

Comment: yeah i mean $M$  ,ok i have the definition a rank $k$ vektor bundle over $M$ is a manifold E together with a smooth "projection" map $ \pi:E \to M $ in such a way that

 1) for each $p\in M$ the fibre $E_p=\pi ^{-1}(${p}$)$ carries the strukture of a k-dim, vektor space

2)for each $p\in M$ there is an open neighborhood $U$and a diffeomorphism $\phi:\pi ^{-1}(U) \to U\times \Bbb R^k$ such that for every  $p\in U$ the map $\phi( E_p)=${p}$\times \Bbb R^k$ and the map$f_p:E_p \to \Bbb R^k $ defined for $\phi(\psi)=(p,f(p))$ ,$\psi \in E_p $ is a vektor space isomorphism

Comment: now i dont really know how to prove the second property

Comment: OK well I suppose you are already given those data for second property for the tangent bundle $TM$ and for the trivial bundle $M\times \mathbb{R}^k$. That is to say, for each $U$, you have $U\times \mathbb{R}^n$ and $U\times \mathbb{R}^k.$ How do you get $U \times \mathbb{R}^{k-n}$ from these?

Comment: orthogonal complement of $R^n$ from$ (U \times R^n)$?

Comment: right ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: so i decompose $T_p \Bbb R^k$ in $T_pM \oplus(T_pM)^\bot$ and just take the diffeomorphism $\phi$ of $ \Bbb R^k$restrict to the orthogonal complement of $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: nice thanks a lot :D